# How Can I .map() and Array that is nested inside an object, inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with getting access to the data I need and wondering if somebody can please advise.

I have data that looks similar to this:

```
Order: [
  {
    id: 1, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 1, price: 20},
        {orderlineId: 2, price: 25}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 3, price: 10},
        {orderlineId: 4, price: 15}
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get access so that I can .map() the OrderLine Array?

I've gone with this, which kinda works but fails with an error part way through:

```
Order.map(order => {
        order.OrderLines.OrderLine.map(line => console.log(line))
      })
```

The above fails with `orderitems.jsx:10 Uncaught TypeError: order.OrderLines.OrderLine.map is not a function`

What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm using this in a nextjs(react) app and simply need to be able to list out each object from the OrderLine array to the page.

---

So the issue appears to be that when there is only one item in the OrderLine array, that array becomes a single object. I shall update my example data.

Example:

```
Order: [
  {
    id: 1, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 1, price: 20},
        {orderlineId: 2, price: 25}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 3, price: 10},
        {orderlineId: 4, price: 15}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: 'Its made up'
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: {orderlineId: 5, price: 5}
    }
  }
]
```

Will solve with if/else

Comment: there is a mistake in your code `id:2` OrderLine `syntax error`. second object `{orderlineId: 4, price: 22}` does not have a closing brace after `price:22`. That is why map is failing half way through.

Comment: You have a curly bracket closing a square bracket and a square bracket closing a curly bracket: `{ [ } ]` <-- That's incorrect

Comment: Sorry, prepped the example data in notepad :), I shall fix.

Comment: The current object you show is not syntactically correct - your code should throw a syntax error. Assuming the syntax is fixed, [then the code doesn't throw the error you get](https://jsbin.com/nubopojuje/edit?js,console). Please provide a [mcve] so we can properly examine why the error is happening.

Comment: Your "parent" array is `Orders` but you are trying to map `Order` (without "s"), which I assume is not defined. Furthermore you are missing the assignment operator `Orders = `. Anyway, in general, I think the data structure could be improved: having `OrderLines` as an object with a single key (`OrderLine`) whose value is an array does not seem right...

Comment: [https://jsbin.com/logexelifi/1/edit?js,console](https://jsbin.com/pigakamabe/edit?js,console). Please provide the sample code and data that *does* fail.

Comment: `order.OrderLines.OrderLine.map` this may happen if the OrderLine isn't an array, so I advise you before doing the map, verify if `order.OrderLines.OrderLine.length > 0`

Comment: On a separate note, `2020-07-21` is not a string or a date, it's a mathematical expression that produces `1992`.

Comment: The issue is that when there is only one 'OrderLine', OrderLine is no longer an array but one object. I shall rephrase my question. Thanks @Wgg12

Comment: Did you see my edited answer accounting for the non-array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're extracting multiple items per array item, I wouldn't use map, but rather reduce:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

You can perform the operation with this line:

```
Order.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur.OrderLines.OrderLine], []);
```

--- EDIT AFTER YOUR EDIT ---

I see now that sometimes the value of OrderLine is an Object, not an array. You could add an array check.

```
Order.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (Array.isArray(cur.OrderLines.OrderLine)) {
        return [...acc, ...cur.OrderLines.OrderLine];
    } else if (cur.OrderLines.OderLine) {
        return [...acc, cur.OrderLines.OrderLine];
    }
}, []);
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const Order = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 1, price: 20
        },
        {orderlineId: 2, price: 25
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    date: 2020-07-21, 
    OrderLines: {
      OrderLine: [
        {orderlineId: 3, price: 10
        },
        {orderlineId: 4, price: 15
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

const orderLines = Order.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (Array.isArray(cur.OrderLines.OrderLine)) {
            return [...acc, ...cur.OrderLines.OrderLine];
        } else if (cur.OrderLines.OderLine) {
            return [...acc, cur.OrderLines.OrderLine];
        }
    }, []);

console.log(orderLines)
```